# Solving ODEs using power series: $x^2y'(x)-y(x)=x^2-x+3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I need to solve the following ODE using power series:

$x^2y'(x)-y(x)=x^2-x+3$

So far this is what I've tried:

$y(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_kx^k = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_kx^k +a_0$

$x^2y'(x)= x^2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ka_kx^{k-1}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ka_kx^{k+1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (k+1)a_{k+1}x^{k} $

So:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (k+1)a_{k+1}x^k - a_kx^k - a_0 = x^2-x+3 $

Assume $x=0$:

$a_0=-3$

Now assume $x=1$:

$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (k+1)a_{k+1} - a_k - a_0 = x^2-x+3 $

So:

$a_{k+1}=a_k/(k+1)  =  a_0/k! $

I'm pretty sure this is full of mistakes but I'm not sure where and how to continue to solve this

Comment: In the expression $x^2y’(x) = …$ in the last sum the last equality is incorrect. And, please, write $n$ instead of $k$

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct your index shifts,
$$
x^2y'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty ka_kx^{k+1}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty(k-1)a_{k-1}x^k
$$

You do not compare values at different points $x$, but the coefficients of equal powers of $x$. So you get
\begin{align}
x^1:&& -a_1&=-1\\
x^2:&& a_1-a_2&=1\\
x^k,\,k>2:&&(k-1)a_{k-1}-a_k&=0
\end{align}

You might note that this gives only one solution, any other solution will not have a power series expansion at $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks, i still don't understand what to do with the right side of the equation? The only thing that i can think of is to differentiate both sides until the right side is zero, but I'm guessing the solution should be a lot simpler...

Comment: The right side is $1·x^2+(-1)·x^1+(-3)·x^0$. You get to match these terms to the terms of equal degree on the left.